# Angular scope doesn't get updated on view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've an angular ng-click event here:

```
eventApp.controller('DetailEventController', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $compile, $timeout, uiCalendarConfig) {
$scope.customRule = { isReadOnly: true, isRegistered: false };
$scope.EventClick = function (event, jsEvent, view) {
                
                var isRegistered;
                console.log(event.character);
                angular.forEach(event.character, function (pvalue, pkey) {
                    for (var item in pvalue.teilnehmer) {
                        if (pvalue.teilnehmer[item] == CurrenUserName) {
                            console.log("User ist bereits angemeldet!");
                            isRegistered = true;
                        } else {
                            console.log("User ist noch nicht angemeldet!");
                            isRegistered = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                $scope.customRule.isRegistered = isRegistered;

                console.log($scope.customRule);
                $scope.eventDetails = event;
                $("#detailEvent").css("display", "block");
            };
}]);
```

When I open the console the $scope.customRule is correct and have the "true" value.

```
User ist bereits angemeldet!
Object { isReadOnly: false, isRegistered: true }
```

But on my View its still "false".

[View Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqnxc.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
            {{customRule}}
            <button title="Anmelden" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="anmelden(eventDetails.id,radio.class.klasse2Event_Id)" ng-disabled="customRule.isReadOnly || customRule.isRegistered">Anmelden</button>
           <button title="Löschen" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="removeEvent(eventDetails.id)" ng-disabled="customRule.isReadOnly">Event Löschen</button>
        </div>
```

So my View dont get the updated scope. Can u tell me why ?

I was reading about the angular apply function. But I dont think that helps me. If I do the apply function after my update:

```
$scope.customRule.isRegistered = isRegistered;
$scope.$apply();
```

I get following error

[Angular Apply Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpA8I.png)

**EDIT:**
I dont get why but I fixed the issue:

Now I dont init the customrules anymore.
I init this one value (isRegistered) directly after the click event.

Before:
$scope.customRule.isRegistered = isRegistered;

After:
$scope.isRegistered = isRegistered;

```
$scope.EventClick = function (event, jsEvent, view) {
                
                var isRegistered;
                var testi;
                
                angular.forEach(event.character, function (pvalue, pkey) {
                    for (var item in pvalue.teilnehmer) {
                        if (pvalue.teilnehmer[item] == CurrenUserName) {
                            console.log("User ist bereits angemeldet!");
                            isRegistered = true;
                            testi = "WAHR";
                        } else {
                            console.log("User ist noch nicht angemeldet!");
                            isRegistered = false;
                            testi = "FALSCH";
                        }
                    }
                });

                $scope.isRegistered = isRegistered;
                $scope.eventDetails = event;
                console.log($scope.customRule);
                //$scope.eventDetails = event;
                $("#detailEvent").css("display", "block");
            };
```

Comment: Post your complete view code. Mostly you could have missed the ng-controller

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you first initialize `$scope.customRule.isRegistered` in your controller. However, since `$scope.$apply()` isn't fixing the issue you most likely are trying to update an `undefined` variable.

I would suggest initializing `$scope.customRule.isRegistered` to `false` or something other than `undefined` that fits within the logic of your application.

As powerful as AngularJS can be, it has trouble updating views with models that change from an `undefined` variable to a defined variable.

Comment: At the top of my Js File I init the customRule: 
$scope.customRule = { isReadOnly: true, isRegistered: false };